# Button with menu

Tags: c#, wpf, button, menu

How to create a Button with menu? The same like on meny windows in Windows.

Example: while opening file:
[link text](http://myih.eu/zdjecie/1275662967buttonmenu.png)

Comment: The link in the question is dead and the question doesn't have enough content to determine what the original intent was. Per the answers, it looks like either a button with a drop-down menu, or a split-button (both of which have several duplicate questions on this site).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iam using this controls pls have a look
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfSplitButton.aspx?msg=3055930 or

this one http://anothersplitbutton.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice simple solution: http://andyonwpf.blogspot.com/2006/10/dropdownbuttons-in-wpf.html